# Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'RefersToRange' of object 'Name' failed

Tags: excel, vba

For a script I'm writing I'm using the single cell named range RowMarker trick to keep track of when users are adding or deleting rows. This happens in the Worksheet_Change event. When a user adds a new row a dropdown (validation) is added in Column B, populated with values from a table in another sheet. When an option in this dropdown is selected another dropdown is added to column F with dynamic data.
At this point the code throws the error:

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'RefersToRange' of object 'Name' failed

As far as I understand it,this means the named range can't be found. If I check the Name Manager it definitely exists and if I iterate over the named ranges in the Sheet it is also listed with the correct address.

Here is the relevant code:

Workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Bug in Excel:
    ' The Worksheet_Activate event does not fire for the sheet that is active
    ' when the workbook is opened, so call it explicitly. Make sure that
    ' Worksheet_Activate() is declared as Public.
    ' Ignore ActiveSheets without (Public) Worksheet_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Call ActiveSheet.Worksheet_Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

WorkSheet:

```
Option Explicit
Public lngRow As Long

Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' Set named marker to track if we add or delete rows
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Me.Names.Add Name:="RowMarker", RefersTo:=Range("$A$1000")
    Set rng1 = Me.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    lngRow = rng1.Row
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Check if row is added or deleted
    Dim isRowAdded As Boolean, isRowDeleted As Boolean, isDoelstellingAdded As Boolean
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim nm As Name
    
    For Each nm In ActiveSheet.Names
        Debug.Print (nm.Name & ": " & nm.RefersTo)
    Next nm
    
    Set rng1 = Me.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    'Set rng1 = Worksheets("Acties (ISO)").Range("RowMarker")
    'Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Acties (ISO)").Range("RowMarker")
    
    If rng1.Row < lngRow Then
        isRowDeleted = True
    ElseIf rng1.Row > lngRow Then
        isRowAdded = True
    End If
    
    ' Check if new Doelstelling was entered in the last row of the table -> skip Insertion and PastInsertion
    ' Check if we're in an empty row at the bottom of the table
    Dim totalTableRows As Long
    totalTableRows = getTotalTableRows
    If Target.Row = totalTableRows + 1 And Target.Column = 2 And isRowAdded = False Then ' + 1 for sheet header
        isDoelstellingAdded = True
        GoTo newDoelstelling
    End If
    
    If rng1.Row = lngRow Then GoTo Insertion
    lngRow = rng1.Row
    
Insertion:
    Dim dsSelectCell As Range
    Set dsSelectCell = Me.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2)
    ' Skip section if we're not adding a row
    If isRowAdded = False Then GoTo PastInsertion
    
    ' Get Doelstellingen from sheet Keuzelijsten as named range
    Dim rngOptions As Range
    Dim rowsOptions As Long
    Dim wsKeuzes As Worksheet
    Set wsKeuzes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keuzelijsten")
    rowsOptions = wsKeuzes.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rngOptions = wsKeuzes.Range("B2:B" & rowsOptions)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "dsOptions", rngOptions

    ' Insert dropdown with Doelstelling names as options
    dsSelectCell.Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=dsOptions"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

PastInsertion:
    ' Exit early if we're adding OR deleting a row OR if no Doelstelling has been set
    If isRowAdded = True Or isRowDeleted = True Or IsEmpty(dsSelectCell) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Get all Actieplannen for selected Doelstelling as dictionary
    Dim dictPlannen As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictPlannen = getPlansDictionary(Me.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value)
    
    ' Insert dropdown with Actieplan names
    If Not Intersect(Target, dsSelectCell) Is Nothing Then
    
        ' Convert plannen dictionary to array
        Dim arrPlannen() As String
        ReDim arrPlannen(dictPlannen.Count)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 0 To dictPlannen.Count - 1
            arrPlannen(j) = dictPlannen.Items(j)
        Next j
        
        ' Insert dropdown with Actieplan names as options
        dsSelectCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
        ' Remove existing dropdown before inserting new one
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(arrPlannen, ",") & ",Nieuw"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
        
        GoTo endOfSub
        
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, dsSelectCell.Offset(0, 4)) Is Nothing Then
        ' Prevent looping when Nieuw changes to new Actieplan value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim colToSelect As Integer
        Dim selectionID As String
        
        ' On selecting Nieuw insert sequential Actieplan
        If Target.Value = "Nieuw" Then
            Dim nrToIterate As String
            nrToIterate = Right(dictPlannen.Items(dictPlannen.Count - 1), 2)
            nrToIterate = Format(CStr(nrToIterate + 1), "00")
            
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            Target.Value = "P" & nrToIterate
            colToSelect = 7
            selectionID = Target.Offset(0, -5).Value
        Else
            ' On selecting Actieplan get dictionary of Actie volgnummers
            Dim dictActionNrs As Scripting.Dictionary
            Set dictActionNrs = getActionNrsDictionary(ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value, ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6).Value)
            ' Insert sequential Actie volgnummer in column G
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = dictActionNrs(dictActionNrs.Count - 1) + 1
            Target.Offset(0, 4).Select
            colToSelect = 8
            selectionID = Target.Offset(0, -5).Value
        End If

        Call afterFullDPAInsert(selectionID, colToSelect)
                
        GoTo endOfSub
                
    End If
        
newDoelstelling:
    ' Skip if we're not adding a new Doelstelling
    If isDoelstellingAdded = False Then GoTo endOfSub

    ' Prevent looping when entering values
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Set Actieplan en Actievolgnummer values
    Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = "P00"
    Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = "0"
        
    ' Add new Doelstelling to table in sheet Keuzelijsten
    Dim newDoelstelling As String, newDoelstellingCode As String
    newDoelstelling = Target.Value
    newDoelstellingCode = Left(newDoelstelling, 3)
    
    Dim wsKeuzelijsten As Worksheet
    Dim tblKeuzes As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Set wsKeuzelijsten = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keuzelijsten")
    Set tblKeuzes = wsKeuzelijsten.ListObjects("Tabel_DS")
    
    Set newRow = tblKeuzes.ListRows.Add
    With newRow
        .Range(1) = newDoelstellingCode
        .Range(2) = newDoelstelling
    End With
    
    ' Sort table DS in sheet Keuzelijsten
    With wsKeuzelijsten
        .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Sort key1:=.Range("A2"), _
              order1:=xlAscending, _
              Header:=xlGuess
    End With
    
    Call afterFullDPAInsert(Target.Offset(0, -1).Value, 7)

endOfSub:
    
    ' Insert today's date in column E
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value = Format(Date, "d/m/yyyy")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

Function getTotalTableRows() As Long
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tableTotalRows As Long
    Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("Tabel_acties")
    tableTotalRows = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
    
    getTotalTableRows = tableTotalRows
    
End Function

Function getPlansDictionary(doelstelling As String) As Dictionary

    Dim rowsDoelen As Long
    rowsDoelen = Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim dictPlannen As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictPlannen = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Loop through all rows to find rows with selected Doelstelling
    For i = 3 To rowsDoelen
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = doelstelling Then
            ' Add all plans for selected Doelstelling to dictionary
            ' Don't add "Nieuw" or empty or duplicate plans
            If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Nieuw" And Not ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "" And Not dictPlannen.Exists(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value) Then
                With dictPlannen
                    .Item(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Set getPlansDictionary = dictPlannen

End Function

Function getActionNrsDictionary(doelstelling As String, actionPlan As String) As Dictionary

    Dim rowsDoelen As Long
    rowsDoelen = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim dictActionNrs As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictActionNrs = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Loop through all rows to find rows with selected Doelstelling
    For i = 3 To rowsDoelen
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = doelstelling And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = actionPlan Then
            ' Add all Actievolgnummers for selected Doelstelling+Actieplan to dictionary
            ' Don't add empty volgnummers
            If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
                With dictActionNrs
                    .Item(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Set getActionNrsDictionary = dictActionNrs

End Function

Function afterFullDPAInsert(selectionID As String, colToSelect As Integer)

    With Me
        ' Sort table after DPA is complete so column A remains sequential
        .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Sort key1:=Range("A3"), _
                      order1:=xlAscending, _
                      Header:=xlGuess
        ' Select correct cell after sorting
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 3 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If Me.Cells(i, 1).Value = selectionID Then Me.Cells(i, colToSelect).Select
        Next i
        ' Trigger Autofit height on selected row
        .Range("A3:A" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.AutoFit
        
    End With

End Function
```

I've been scratching my head about this for hours now. I've tried every way to define named ranges, but I don't understand how this line can resolve in the first change event, yet fail in the subsequent event.

Any help is much appreciated, I'm pretty new to vba.

I've tried:

- with or without RefersToRange
- specifying the named range by the Worksheet name i.e. `Set rng1 = Worksheets("Acties (ISO)").Range("RowMarker")`
  Then Excel just crashes with no error
- specifying the named range by the Worksheet name i.e. `Set rng1 = Sheets("Acties (ISO)").Range("RowMarker")`
  This throws the same error
- prefacing it with ThisWorkbook i.e. `Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Acties (ISO)").Range("RowMarker")`
  Then Excel just crashes with no error
- prefacing it with ThisWorkbook i.e. `Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Acties (ISO)").Range("RowMarker")`
  This throws the same error

EDIT: I've uploaded a reduced testcase which throws the same errors here: [WeTransfer Verbeterplan-TEST.xlsm](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0e9e6ac02228a4499f1e24640ebd0cad20231205084638/7241ad). I've also updated the code above to show everything. It's a lot and probably pretty messy, like I said I'm pretty new to VBA.
Any further help would be very much appreciated because I am at a loss and my boss needs this file to work again asap.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the code provided.  I'm just getting _Sheet1!RowMarker: =Sheet1!$A$1001_ printed in the Immediate window and no errors on the `Set rng1....` line.

Comment: As a side note `Dim isRowAdded, isRowDeleted, isDoelstellingAdded As Boolean` only defines `isDoelstellingAdded` as boolean, the others are variants.  Use `Dim isRowAdded as Boolean, isRowDeleted as Boolean, isDoelstellingAdded As Boolean` to define them all as boolean.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I suppose I should comment out all following code and uncomment block by block to see where it fails. Although I still fail to see how any code could make that line throw an error when it was fine 1 change event earlier...
Good shout about the variables, I assume this is a general rule then for all types?

Comment: Yes, a general rule when declaring variables.  Not sure if you're manually typing `Option Explicit` or not as it isn't on the `WorkBook_Open` event (might not be the first bit of code in the workbook module) - _Tools > Options > Require Variable Declaration_ to automatically add it to new modules.

Comment: I tried as is and with renaming the sheet to "Acties (ISO)", adding rows or just changing values but no error, I'm afraid. I at first thought adding the RowMaker name on Activate if it already exists would cause an issue with making RowMaker1 and RowMaker2 or something but it simply overwrites the existing one, no problem. Have you tried in a new workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarassing...
There was an infinite loop in my code where the change event kept getting called over and over, hence the crashes.
Have I mentioned I hate VBA and it's extremely limited number of events :)?

Anyway thanks for looking into it guys/gals! And sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the error, and suspect the issue is due to scope. The fact that you're using `activesheet` in your test and `me` when setting your range has me wondering if the name somehow exists on a different sheet? I don't think it's scoped at the workbook level, as your debug test at a sheet level wouldn't find it. Either way, give the below a go:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Check if row is added or deleted
    Dim isRowAdded, isRowDeleted, isDoelstellingAdded As Boolean
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim nm As Name
    
    For Each nm In ActiveSheet.Names
        if nm.Name = "RowMarker" then
            Set rng1 = nm.RefersToRange
            exit for
        end if
    Next nm
```

This should work around the issue by setting the range when you know it will pop up (given your debug testing says it's being found this way). As this is no longer explicitly defined, you should probably throw in some error handling if it can't be found i.e. `if rng1 is nothing then msgbox "oops, name not found", vbcritical: exit sub`

Comment: It definitely  exists on this sheet because I had to modify your code to make it work: `If nm.Name = **"'Acties (ISO)'!RowMarker"** Then`. It still fails with the same error on `Set rng1 = ...`.